# Use Android API to read Google Fit activity data according to different data sources

Tags: google-fit

I have an Android APP that reads Google Fit activity data e.g. DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA. The step count can come from either a mobile phone or a Wear OS watch. The App would need to display the step count recorded by the watch and the count reported by the mobile separately, as well as the combined total.

Can you please advise how to achieve it via Android API (not REST API)?

Answer (score 0):

Recorded sessions capture its sensor data. It could be either from the Phone, Watch or other sources. As described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record?hl=en#subscribe) it is necessary to add a subscription if you want to request background collection of sensor data in your app. That being said, subscription will sync data recorded from your source together with retrieve data from other sources.